# How to split a xml in Mule using splitter

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, mule, mule-studio

I am new to mule ... I have an xml as payload :-

```
<com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.DataRequest>
  <id>21</id>
  <name>a </name>
  <age>23</age>
  <designation>gfgf</designation>
</com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.DataRequest>
```

Now I want to extract each value and insert into database ... How can I split each values ??
Do I need to use a splitter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you do not want to deserialize this XML entity to an object.

The best is then to use `xpath` MEL XPath expressions in your JDBC outbound endpoint query.

MEL Xpath documentation: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference#MuleExpressionLanguageReference-XpathandRegex

JDBC outbound endpoint documentation showing old-style expressions in the query: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference#JDBCTransportReference-BasicInsert/Update/DeleteStatements

Just use MEL instead of the old style the MuleSoft doc shows.